# How can I import an html attribute from a website into a google sheets document?

Tags: html, google-sheets, xpath, google-sheets-formula

[I want to have a readout for "data-original-title"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNF9F.png)

I tried this (H2 is the website link):

`=IMPORTXML(H2;"//div[@id='mainContent']//dd[@class='col-6 col-xl-7'][1]`

No readout but also no Error

Also tried this,

`=IMPORTXML(H2;"//div[@id='mainContent']//dd[@class='col-6 col-xl-7']//attribute[@data-original-title]")`

but got N/A

I think it just doesnt print the value of the attribute in google sheets, but Im unsure and not that familiar with xpath. Can anyone help?

Comment: You can try the xpath in browser's console, e.g. in FF `$x("//div[@id='mainContent']//dd[@class='col-6 col-xl-7']/@data-original-title")`. Also, Please, take some time to read [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer myself jsut by trial and error.

```
=IMPORTXML(H2;"//div[@id='mainContent']//dd[@class='col-6 col-xl-7']/span/@data-original-title")
```

This worked